# How to view request / response duration?

Tags: paw-app

Where in Paw 2 can I see the duration of a request / response? I suppose I could subtract the response time from the request time but there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's shown in the title bar right after the request is completed.

[image: Request / Response time in Paw (HTTP Client)]

Though, as of version Paw 2.1.1, this time isn't accurate enough to judge of your server or network connection. The underlying HTTP library is optimized for logging / debugging and is loosing time between connecting, sending, receving, etc.

Comment: Note that it's planned to be fixed, and once done, it will be displayed also in the Info tab of the HTTP Exchange, as part of more accurate metrics.

Comment: Totally off topic here, but I think you [better take a look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252360/are-there-any-guidelines-around-which-se-site-should-host-a-given-question-tag). Good luck, and sorry for the hassle!

Comment: You're absolutely right @ShadowWizard, I changed the tag to "paw-app". Thanks!